# Latin Root Word and Meaning of Imperative and Declarative

Tags: classical-latin

What are the Latin root words for the English words "imperative" and "declarative"? What are their respective meanings?

Comment: Welcome!  These sorts of questions can be pretty easily answered with online tools like etymonline.com – see, for example, their entry on [*imperative*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=imperative&allowed_in_frame=0).  Is that what you are looking for?  Or is there something more specific about your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymonline.com offers this for [*imperative*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=imperative&allowed_in_frame=0):

> from Late Latin *imperativus* "pertaining to a command," from *imperat-*, past participle stem of *imperare* "to command, requisition," from assimilated form of *in-* "into, in" + *parare* "prepare"

For *declarative*, it points to the entry on [*declare*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=declare&allowed_in_frame=0):

> from Latin *declarare* "make clear, reveal, disclose, announce," from *de-* intensive prefix + *clarare* "clarify," from *clarus* "clear"